# Can anyone identify this set?

Tags: set-identification

https://www.gumtree.com/p/other-baby-stuff/various-bits-of-lego-all-for-%C2%A35/1183678235

Can anyone identify this set? Is it even genuine LEGO?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Welcome! This collection of pieces might contain *some* LEGO pieces, but is mostly another brand. The bottoms of the bricks and plates have patterns that are not typical for LEGO, and LEGO does not make a large wedge plate like the light-grey one on the right. Furthermore, LEGO did never make a large tree stump and tree with face as shown in the middle of the picture. As such, even though the seller claims this is "LEGO", it is not.

Comment: *This collection of pieces might contain* some *LEGO pieces* – For what it’s worth, [these pieces](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aOr41.jpg) have a strong similarity to existing pieces or are very close replicas.